# Trying to create a macro that will drag a formula to the last line with data

Tags: excel

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(C[-3])>0,C[-3]*6,C[-3])"
Range("L10").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L10:L32"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("L10:L32").Select
```

I need the last line with data. L32 will not always be the last line.

Comment: Last line in a specific column?

Comment: You will also want to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Answer (score 1):

This will find the last used row in column A and fill the formula to that row starting in L10

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim lstrw As Long
    lstrw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range(.Cells(10, "L"), .Cells(.lstrw, "L")).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEFT(C[-3])>0,C[-3]*6,C[-3])"
End With
```